# PHP mysqli: escape strings saving strange

Tags: php, mysqli

I am writing a code editor using CodeMirror.  I am going to be saving Javascripts in a mySQL database.  Because Javascript uses the `'` symbol quite a bit, I have had to use `mysqli->real_escape_string()` on the textarea
input.

When I retrieve the source from the scripts table, it still has the escaped characters.

So, if i were to insert this:

```
this.update('something');
```

You would have

```
this.update(\'something\');
```

Is there some way to reverse the process?

Comment: Verify that the input is not being pre-escaped before `real_escape_string()`. Due to *magic quotes* or `*slashes()` for example.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CodeMirror, but its possible its escaping "'" chars before submitting. So it may not be mysqli->real_escape_string()'s fault.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use mysqli prepared statements?
If so, you shouldn't use `mysqli->real_escape_string()` then
If don't - then you have `magic_quotes_gpc` on and you have to turn it off

Answer (score 0):

You can always try using [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

It is weird though that your real_escape_string doesn't work properly. It should not leave the slashes. It could be though that your host has magic_quotes_runtime turned on. You can turn it off with `set_magic_quotes_runtime(0)`.

Maybe you are double escaping it by both using `mysql_real_escape_string` and `addslashes`?

The best practice though is to change your code to use bind variables, rather than using the string escaping.

Example:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare( "UPDATE tablename SET favorite_color = ?, age = ?, description = ? WHERE user = ?" );

// we would have a bind looking like this:
$query->bind_param( 'sibs', 'red', 27, $some_blob, $variable );
$query->execute();
```

A decent explanation about this (and SQL Injection) can be found [here](http://simon.net.nz/articles/protecting-mysql-sql-injection-attacks-using-php/).

Comment: my php.ini has this setting already: magic_quotes_runtime = Off

Comment: Ok, it was the magic_quotes setting for GET and POST.  Changed it, it worked like a charm.  Also, thanks for the binding info.

Comment: Ok cool. I'm happy it's solved. If my answer helped, don't forget to +1 and tick it as correct. Tnx!

Comment: @Downvoter: Please clarify why you downvote this answer when it has fixed this guy's issue?